# Getting Invalid block tag: 'ckeditor_placeholder' when using ckeditor with Gerbi CMS

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I am trying to upgrade an install of Gerbi CMS (django-page-cms package name) and I keep receiving the following error.

[image]

Here is the template code (client name removed).

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load pages_tags markup chunks %}

{% block title %}
    {% if current_page %}
        {% show_content current_page "title" %}
    {% else %}
        << Client Name >>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block pagecontent %}
    {% if current_page %}
        {% ckeditor_placeholder "Page Title" with ckeditor %}
        {% ckeditor_placeholder "Page Content" with ckeditor %}
        {% imageplaceholder "Header Image" as header_imgsrc %}

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <hgroup class="heading-section">
                        <h1>{{ page_title }}</h1>
                    </hgroup>
                </div>{# /.span12 #}
            </div>{# /.row #}
            <div class="row-fluid mobile-pad">
                <div class="span12">
                    {{ content|markdown }}
                </div>{# /.span12 #}
            </div>{# /.row l-athletes #}
        </div>{# /.container #}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have followed the ckeditor setup correctly and have the required config stuff in my *settings.py* file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ....
    'ckeditor',
    ....
)

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'width': 600,
        'height': 300,
        'toolbar': 'Full',
    }
}
```

I have also run `collecstatic` and `syncdb` already to try and get the files where they need to be but Gerbi CMS isn't playing nice with ckeditor.

The packages are:

```
django-page-cms==1.6.2
django-ckeditor==4.4.7
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ckeditor_placeholder template tag isn't loaded.

change this line:

```
{% load pages_tags markup chunks %}
```

to this

```
{% load pages_tags markup chunks ckeditor_placeholder %}
```

Comment: This was it. Must have missed that in the documentation. Thanks Stuart!